# Is there any queue like mechanism in Java Batch?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, batch-processing, java-ee-7, jsr352

I'm looking into [Java Batch](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/batch/api/package-summary.html), and found a couple of [good](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/batch-1965499.html) [examples](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/wls/CNFGD/batch-apps.htm#CNFGD369). But, I'm not sure whether the independent jobs will run concurrently/in-parallel or sequentially. If they will run in-parallel, or concurrently, then how to set the limit on concurrency? Further, is there any queue maintained internally -- I know about JobRepository, but in which fashion jobs will be picked?

**Note:** *It's not about defining flows by split to run concurrently on multiple threads, neither it's about partitioning the input in order to process a range of data in parallel.*

Comment: The Batch 1.0 specification does not include in its scope questions about how jobs are scheduled/dispatched/orchestrated, but simply how they are defined and coded in XML and Java.  So it depends on the implementation you are using.   Which are you using?

Comment: I'm planning to use Oracle's implementation, by following the example given here, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/batch-1965499.html .

Comment: So you're running in GlassFish?   If so, this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26757550/glassfish-set-max-number-of-concurrent-batch-jobs) may help you.    That seems to provides a way to throttle jobs already started, if I'm skimming that correctly.  Of course, you could throttle the thread issuing the JobOperator.start() in various ways as well.